Yandex Browser is not opening website for the first time
I am testing a website and there is an issue where I can't open that website in Yandex browser and Telegram in-app browser for the first time. IMO the issue is related to redirection.
When I enter domain name, website is not loading and showing me in Browser, and goes "Web page is not available" in Russian. Then I realized browser is sending it with http:// protocol without an 's', so it is not opening the website.
Then if I type it with https:// with an 's' it is loading the website. After that even if I search website up hundred times with http:// without an 's' it is still loading and opening my website.
So after entering https:// no matter how much I enter the website with http:// it is still opening, but for the first time it does not load the website
If you ever faced with this problem and found a solution before, please let me know.


One of my colleagues found a solution and the problem was with Hetzner load balancer. Here is the solution:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWkatWuaxls&ab_channel=Majestic.cloud
